# PHP CS Fixer Symfony & PSR2 rule do not exist

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

I'm using grumphp to check my code before committing and it's telling me:

> F  [UnexpectedValueException]
>     Rule "symfony" does not exist.
>
> Exception trace:
>    () at /Users/foo/projects/bar/app/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/src/FixerFactory.php:181
>    PhpCsFixer\FixerFactory->useRuleSet() at /Users/foo/projects/bar/app/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/src/Console/ConfigurationResolver.php:264
>    PhpCsFixer\Console\ConfigurationResolver->getFixers() at /Users/foo/projects/bar/app/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/src/Console/Command/FixCommand.php:164
>    PhpCsFixer\Console\Command\FixCommand->execute() at /Users/foo/projects/bar/app/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:261
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /Users/foo/projects/bar/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:817
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/foo/projects/bar/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/foo/projects/bar/app/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:116
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/foo/projects/bar/app/vendor/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer/php-cs-fixer:45

Tried executing it manually and it tells me the same.

So I started digging into the code

I can see there is a ruleSet and the fixer factory is calling $ruleset->getRules() but that is returning only the rule Name for symfony, instead of the 91 array keys:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "symfony"
]
```

The rule_set is

```
'@Symfony' => array(
                '@PSR2' => true,
                'binary_operator_spaces' => array(
                    'align_double_arrow' => false,
                    'align_equals' => false,
                ),
                'blank_line_after_opening_tag' => true,
                'blank_line_before_return' => true,
                'cast_spaces' => true,
                'class_definition' => array('singleLine' => true),
                'concat_space' => array('spacing' => 'none'),
                'declare_equal_normalize' => true,
                'function_typehint_space' => true,
                'hash_to_slash_comment' => true,
                'heredoc_to_nowdoc' => true,
                'include' => true,
                'lowercase_cast' => true,
                'method_separation' => true,
                'native_function_casing' => true,
                'new_with_braces' => true,
                'no_alias_functions' => true,
                'no_blank_lines_after_class_opening' => true,
                'no_blank_lines_after_phpdoc' => true,
                'no_empty_comment' => true,
                'no_empty_phpdoc' => true,
                'no_empty_statement' => true,
                'no_extra_consecutive_blank_lines' => array(
                    'curly_brace_block',
                    'extra',
                    'parenthesis_brace_block',
                    'square_brace_block',
                    'throw',
                    'use',
                ),
                'no_leading_import_slash' => true,
                'no_leading_namespace_whitespace' => true,
                'no_mixed_echo_print' => array('use' => 'echo'),
                'no_multiline_whitespace_around_double_arrow' => true,
                'no_short_bool_cast' => true,
                'no_singleline_whitespace_before_semicolons' => true,
                'no_spaces_around_offset' => true,
                'no_trailing_comma_in_list_call' => true,
                'no_trailing_comma_in_singleline_array' => true,
                'no_unneeded_control_parentheses' => true,
                'no_unreachable_default_argument_value' => true,
                'no_unused_imports' => true,
                'no_whitespace_before_comma_in_array' => true,
                'no_whitespace_in_blank_line' => true,
                'normalize_index_brace' => true,
                'object_operator_without_whitespace' => true,
                'php_unit_fqcn_annotation' => true,
                'phpdoc_align' => true,
                'phpdoc_annotation_without_dot' => true,
                'phpdoc_indent' => true,
                'phpdoc_inline_tag' => true,
                'phpdoc_no_access' => true,
                'phpdoc_no_alias_tag' => true,
                'phpdoc_no_empty_return' => true,
                'phpdoc_no_package' => true,
                'phpdoc_scalar' => true,
                'phpdoc_separation' => true,
                'phpdoc_single_line_var_spacing' => true,
                'phpdoc_summary' => true,
                'phpdoc_to_comment' => true,
                'phpdoc_trim' => true,
                'phpdoc_types' => true,
                'phpdoc_var_without_name' => true,
                'pre_increment' => true,
                'return_type_declaration' => true,
                'self_accessor' => true,
                'short_scalar_cast' => true,
                'single_blank_line_before_namespace' => true,
                'single_class_element_per_statement' => true,
                'single_quote' => true,
                'space_after_semicolon' => true,
                'standardize_not_equals' => true,
                'ternary_operator_spaces' => true,
                'trailing_comma_in_multiline_array' => true,
                'trim_array_spaces' => true,
                'unary_operator_spaces' => true,
                'whitespace_after_comma_in_array' => true,
            ),
```

Crashing here in the end:

```
  public function useRuleSet(RuleSetInterface $ruleSet)
    {
        $fixers = array();
        $fixersByName = array();
        $fixerConflicts = array();

        $fixerNames = array_keys($ruleSet->getRules());
        foreach ($fixerNames as $name) {
       ----->     if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->fixersByName)) {
          throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('Rule "%s" does not exist.', $name));
            }
```

ResolveSet() works as expected
somewhere in between resolveSet() and the fixerFactory the array keys get lost
I'll investigate further, any hints or recommendations?

Issues on github:
https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/2518
https://github.com/phpro/grumphp/issues/281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

You need to Escape the arguments with another @ !

> @@Symfony

It would look like this:

```
phpcsfixer2:
    allow_risky: false
    cache_file: ~
    config: ~
    rules: ['@@Symfony']
    using_cache: false
    path_mode: ~
    verbose: true
```

Hope this helps someone!

Or you can build a workaround which has lot's of other functionalities:

php_cs.dist

```
<?php

$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    ->exclude(['vendor','tmpl_c'])
    ->name('*.php5');

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules([
        '@Symfony' =>  true,
        'encoding' => false,
        'psr0' => false,
        'psr4' => false,
        'self_accessor' => false,
        'no_short_echo_tag' => true,
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'short'],
    ])
    ->setFinder($finder);
```

Updated grumphp.yml

```
parameters:
    bin_dir: "./vendor/bin"
    git_dir: "."
    hooks_dir: ~
    hooks_preset: local
    stop_on_failure: false
    ignore_unstaged_changes: false
    process_async_limit: 10
    process_async_wait: 1000
    process_timeout: 60
    ascii:
        failed: grumphp-grumpy.txt
        succeeded: grumphp-happy.txt
    tasks:
        git_blacklist:
            keywords:
                - "die("
                - "var_dump("
                - "print_f("
                - "dump("
                - "dd("
                - "exit;"
            triggered_by: ["php"]
        git_commit_message:
            matchers:
                - /SER-([0-9]*)/
            case_insensitive: true
            multiline: true
            additional_modifiers: ''
        git_conflict: ~
        phpcsfixer2:
            allow_risky: false
            cache_file: ~
            config: config/php_cs.dist
            rules: []
            using_cache: false
            path_mode: ~
            verbose: true
        phpmd:
            exclude: []
            ruleset: ['cleancode', 'codesize', 'naming']
            triggered_by: ["php"]
        phpparser:
            ignore_patterns: []
            kind: php7
            triggered_by: ["php"]
            visitors: {}
        phpunit: ~
        phpversion:
            project: "7.0"
        shell: ~

    testsuites: []
    extensions: []
```

The problem was Grumphp using the Symfony service container,

The php-cs Fixer options are made **lowercase and the @ sign is stripped away** which causes the cs fixer to not find the rule!

This happens in the Symfony service container!

http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-parameters

> If you want to use a string that starts with an @ sign as a parameter
>   value (e.g. a very safe mailer password) in a YAML file, you need to
>   escape it by adding another @ sign (this only applies to the YAML
>   format)